# Javascript async functions doesn't work in android chrome from js in url bar

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I made a simple script to run in my android chrome. It comes that there are 2 scenarios working differently:

first one `javascript:(alert("try"))` works with no problems

second one `javascript:(async function test(){alert("try")};test())` does NOT work

obv it's not what i am trying to do but in my desired script i need an await or a generic sleep. What can i do?

edit: the curious thing is that setInterval works fine... but `javascript:(let prova = "try";alert(prova))` doesn't work

edit2: i did it, it took a very bad headache but now works. There are things that doesn't work for some reason but a workaround can always be found

here's what's the final working version

```
javascript:(setInterval(() =>{setTimeout(() => {document.querySelector('.nameofthetextareaselector').value="value i wanted to put here";document.querySelector('.nameofthebuttontosend').click();new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {document.querySelector('.nameofthesecondbutton').click()},2000));resolve},2000)},5000))
```

It edits the textarea, send it, click another button after some seconds and repeat

things that not worked: assign anything with let, const or directly the name of the variable, nesting promises, using async-await, using try-catch, etc...

Now i am happy that all works but i want to know why all these things doesn't seem to work (only on android chrome, on windows chrome all these things worked)

Comment: _"obv it's not what i am trying to do"_: What _are_ you trying to do? Understanding that problem, rather than the one you've posed, would help us help you.

Comment: change a value of a textbox, wait 2 secs and press a button

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing right now is just declaring a function without calling it, you can add `()` at the end of javascript function to execute it right away.

`javascript:(async function test(){alert("try")}())`

Comment: edited, i forgot to write it down but i did it and didn't work